# How to recognize the interactivePopGestureRecognizer is successfully proceed when swipe to pop viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I want to clean up some properties when user swipe page to pop viewController, just make it works as same as tapping back button.

I try the following code, but it fails because not every swipe is successful every time. Some swipes to pop might fail because the gesture is cancelled.

And I can not find good enough delegate in UIGestureRecognizer (to find something like `touchesEnded`). Neither can I use target action because action will be called too many times.

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
}
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   viewModel.goBackPage(isSwipeBack: true)
   return true
}
```

How do I solve trigger `backButtonPressed` in swipe to pop viewController at the right moment?

Comment: Why don't you use `viewDidDisappear` ?

Comment: Because push to the next viewController will trigger viewDidDisappear, too.
But you give me one idea, maybe I can use the state of gestureRecognizer to set a flag `isSwipeBegan` to decide if I was swiping back in viewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, with help of @Sam_M (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6739471/sam-m) 's comment, I solved it!!

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   if isSwipePop {
      viewModel.goBackPage(withPopViewController: true)
   }
}


func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .possible, .began, .changed:
        isSwipePop = true
    default:
        isSwipePop = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Glad to help:) You can also use `if self.isBeingDismissed || self.isMovingFromParentViewController { 
    }` to determine whether you're going forwards or backwards.

Comment: You can also combine your cases that have the same outcome like `case .possible, .began, .changed:` and you also don't need to use `break` in swift switch. Each case will automatically break the switch.

Comment: Hi @Sam_M , I updated a answer beloew, maybe you are interested :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out `viewWillDisappear` will be called even if swipe was not successful. So I changed it to be this:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    print("viewDidDisappear \(self)")
    if isSwipePop && isMovingFromParentViewController {
        viewModel.goBackPage(withPopViewController: true)
    }

    isSwipePop = false
}
```

---

For more information this is the scenarios of swiping from page two to page one.

Swipe to page one from page two, release in the half way swiping to page one, and it bounces back to page two:

viewWillDisappear Page Two
viewWillAppear Page One
viewWillDisappear Page One
viewDidDisappear Page One
viewWillAppear Page Two
viewDidAppear Page Two

Swipe to page one from page two successfully:

viewWillDisappear Page Two
viewWillAppear Page One
viewDidDisappear Page Two
viewDidAppear Page One